# Not get point Ruby operator with dot

Tags: ruby

I'm familiar with Ruby operator and its work flow and use cases but at a place I'm confused with . in expression.

`3.**2+1` is giving result `27`

instead `3.**2` gives `9` and

`3**2+1` gives `10` it is okay but I'm confuse on `3.**2+1`

anything that I'm missing with dot . operator here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Operators in ruby are backed by methods. So `3 ** 2` is functionally equivalent to "call method `**` on `3` and pass `2` as an argument".

You can invoke these methods directly too (`1.+(2)` instead of `1+2`), which is what that dot does in this case. And because operators have different precedence than method calls, you're seeing these different results.

```
3.** 2 + 1 == 3.**(2+1)
# but
3 ** 2 + 1 == (3 ** 2) + 1
```

Comment: Interesting. So, adding the dot makes it a standard method chain (in the same way one might call `3.is_a?(Integer)`).

Comment: @JohnP exactly, operator precedence rules only apply when using operators literally. (explicit method calls don't have precedence issues in the first place)

Comment: You might consider mentioning the problem would go away if OP used `3.0**2` instead of `3.**2`.

Comment: @pjs: Hm, interesting. Do you think that's what they originally were going for?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yup, I think that's what they were going for.  I always like to make zeroes explicit on floats, such as `0.1` vs `.1` or `3.0` vs `3.`, but I'm met a fair number of folks who don't when writing down the math and there are some programming languages where that works.

Comment: @Stefan: "explicit method calls don't have precedence issues in the first place" - they do, though. :) Have you ever had you `do/end` block be passed to a wrong method?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes indeed, blocks have their own issues :-)